# Laravel 5.8 - Specified type Model for route paramteters

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.8

I have a routing conflict issue in my Laravel application (version 5.8).

Here are the 2 routes that are problematics :

```php
Route::post('/projets/{projet}/{redirect}','ProjetController@update')->name('projets.update');
Route::post('/projets/export/excel', 'ProjetController@exportExcel')->name('projets.exportExcel');
```

The first parameter "projet" is supposed to be a Model Object "Projet" and "redirect" is a String.

But i don't have specified the type of these parameters and i would like to know if someone have an idea on how i can specified that the "projet" parameter is an Object "Projet" (if this is possible ?).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wildcard routes need to come after any other route that might match it.

Comment: @aynber yes i have change the routing configuration like you say, it works fine now thanks ! And do you if this is possible to specify the type Model Object for a routing parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, in your ProjetController `update` method you can use this signature:

```
public function update(Request $request, App\Projet $projet, string $redirect){
   // Use posted values with $request Object,
   // Use $projet model
   // Use $redirect string

}
```

And you can explore details in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding).

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, already done : `public function update(ProjetRequest $projetRequest, Projet $projet,String $redirect)` but wasn't working with this...

Comment: What about your parameters? Can you show us your request url?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, the issue is solved now, the problem came from the routing conflict configuration.